# ¿Como puedo dar privilegios a las sessiones SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estuve investigando y tengo una duda. Sé que para crear una sesión es:

```
 CREATE LOGIN user WITH PASSWORD = 'pass';
```

Y mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo le doy privilegios de lectura, escritura y asignarle una tabla a ese usuario con código SQL?

Answer (score 2):

en SQL Server 2012 o superior, si quieres asignar un [rol a nivel de servidor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188659.aspx), por ejemplo `sysadmin`, que le da privilegios de administrador, puedes hacerlo con:

```
create login [MiUsuario] with password = 'MiPassword';
alter server role [sysadmin] add member [MiUsuario];
```

Si quieres asignarle un rol en una base de datos, crea el usuario para la DB y luego le asignas el permiso, por ejemplo con db_datareader le das permisos de lectura:

```
use MiBase;
create user [MiUsuario] for login [MiUsuario];
alter role [db_datareader] add member [MiUsuario];
```

Finalmente, puedes darle permisos an nivel de objeto, por ejemplo, tablas, valiéndote de la instrucción [grant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187965.aspx):

```
grant select on MiTabla to [MiUsuario];
grant execute on MiStoredProc to [MiUsuario];
```